# Twitter Rate Limit with oAuth

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

How do I implement the oauth_token into my request?

When making a request to twitter's REST API:

> https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=shakira

I get the rate limit error (Rate limit exceeded. Clients may not make more than 150 requests per hour.)

I have created a twitter application and received an access token, which I am now trying to use to boost my rate limit to 350. I have tried adding it to the url, like so:

> https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?oauth_token=MyAccessTokenGoesHere&screen_name=shakira

But that isn't working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OAuth parameters should go to the header of your request, not in the URL. For more details check the following article in the documentation:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request